# Error 400 redirect_uri_mismatch while request GoogleAdwords API

Tags: google-oauth

I would like to attempt a GoogleAdwords request:

1. I have generated my Client ID and Client secret from Google API Console Credential Page ( (its type is **other**)
2. I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication) article to test my credentials
3. I have set input information as follows in [this page](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step1&scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords&url=https://&content_type=application/json&http_method=GET&useDefaultOauthCred=checked&oauthEndpointSelect=Google&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth&oauthTokenEndpointValue=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token&includeCredentials=unchecked&accessTokenType=bearer&autoRefreshToken=unchecked&accessType=offline&forceAprovalPrompt=checked&response_type=code):

[image]

4. If I click on Authorize API button
   [image]

then I get the error message **Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch**

what should I do more to prevent this error message?

Comment: What did you set in the redirect uri in the Google developer console when you created your client. It must exactly match the redirect uri you are are using in your requst.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps at [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention)

In particular, steps 3 and 4. They type should be web app and you need to add the oauth2 playground URL as a valid redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your OAuth2 server, you should set `redirect_uri` is `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground`. Because your OAuth2 server must check `redirect_uri` in http request and `redirect_uri`specified previous before execute further actions.